# Is this inequality correct? $a^7b+b^7c+c^7a \le3$ if $ a^6 + b^6 +c^6 = 3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want to verify the validity of this inequality, and if it is true, I want to prove it

if a,b and c are positive real numbers and $ a^6 + b^6 +c^6 = 3$, then
$$ a^7b+b^7c+c^7a \le3 $$

Use an CBS inequality
$$ (a^7b+b^7c+c^7a)^2 \le (a^{14} +b^{14}+c^{14})(a^2+b^2+c^2) $$ but $a^{14} +b^{14}+c^{14} \ge 3$.
Is there a way to prove the inequality or is it false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is true. Here is the proof. By AM-GM we have: $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^7b \leq \sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a^9b^3+a^6+a^6}{3}=(…)$$

Since $a^6+b^6+c^6=3$, $$(…)={1\over 3}\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^9b^3 + {2\over 3}\cdot 3 = (…)$$

If we manage to show that $\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^9b^3 \leq 3,$ then:$$(…) \leq {1\over 3}\cdot 3+ {2\over 3}\cdot 3 = 3.$$

Now the inequality $ \sum_{\text{cyc}}a^9b^3 \leq 3 $ is equivalent to $ \sum_{\text{cyc}}a^9b^3 \leq a^6+b^6+c^6$. Let us multiply this inequality by $3= a^6+b^6+c^6$ to homogenize it:

$$ 3\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^9b^3 \leq (a^6+b^6+c^6)^2.$$

And this is just the [Vasc’s inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c227495h1244386_problem_12_vasc_inequality) for numbers $a^3,b^3,c^3$. In short, if we put $x=a^3, \;y=b^3,\; z=c^3$ then $3(x^3y+y^3z+z^3x) \leq (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2$ holds because $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2- 3 (x^3y+y^3z+z^3x) = \sum_{\text{cyc}}(x^2-2xy+yz-z^2+zx)^2.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I need this proof as a step to solve one of the problems that was presented to me. Would you allow me to transfer this step?

Comment: Glad to help. I’m not sure what you mean by “transfer”. If you want to use it in your work then sure.